# During handling of the above exception, another exception occured

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

so basically what I'm trying to do is read a column from a csv file to an array then do calculations with that array. I have successfully gotten the array 'rawSunlightData' from the csv file but for some reason every time I try to select a variable from 'raySunlightData' array I get the error [During handling of the above exception, another exception occured] I can print the whole rawSunlightData but can't print individual values like rawSunlightData[0]

```
    cleanSunlightData = []
    rawSunlightData = pd.read_csv('Average daily sunlight per month.csv', header = None)
    rawSunlightData = rawSunlightData.drop(rawSunlightData.columns[[0]], axis=1)
    print(rawSunlightData[0])
    i = 0
    while i <= len(rawSunlightData):

        arrayDivider = []

        m = 0
        while m < 12:
            x = i + m
            print(x)
            m += 1

        i += 12
```

the error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
 File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/kennethwong/Desktop/Singapore crop yield /Downloaded data/Data cleaner.py", line 67, in <module>
cleanSunlightData()
File "/Users/kennethwong/Desktop/Singapore crop yield /Downloaded data/Data cleaner.py", line 46, in cleanSunlightData
 print(rawSunlightData[0])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4115, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: @ALollz sorry ! I have added the error message :)

Comment: Can you add the error message as code formatted text instead of an image please?

Comment: By the way, the error message is not "During handling of the above exception, another exception occured", it's "key error 0"

Comment: Also, please provide a short sample of the input data, enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: @MadPhysicist im sorry ! have done so

Comment: Could you post the data as text as well? I can't copy a screenshot into my editor to play with. Unless your question pertains to graphical inputs or outputs, there's rarely ever a reason to use screenshots on SO.

Answer (score 1):

its okay guy I found out why, im still new to coding so I make mistakes... when you pull data from csv file and store it in a data frame, it is NOT an array ! you will have to convert it to an array by array.to_records()